# Angular JS animation with UI router

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation, angular-ui-router

In my application i use animation and ui-route

my app route like this

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/{lang:(?:he|en)}/',
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    }).state('app.home', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: "Assets/app/templates/home.html",
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
    .state('app.activity', {
        url: "activity",
        templateUrl: "Assets/app/templates/gallery.html",
        controller: 'galleryController'
    })
```

The animate work just when i moved from language he to language en,
but when i moving to one of the other page (inside the language) like from home to activity page the animation does not work.
How can i make the animation to work either for "sub pages"

thanks